# Yosemite Launchpad Editing or Editor?

Tags: osx-yosemite, launchpad

Is there an editor for the Yosemite Launchpad available? I'd like to quickly set up folders and screens. The old one is no longer supported. If not, how do I edit the file responsible for the layout? Also, can I copy it into from one user to another?